# shinydashboard: my boxes don't want to take up the whole column

Tags: user-interface, layout, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm building an app with a lot of `box`es using shinydashboard. Ideally I'd like to have three boxes in one `fluidRow`. If I just plop them in, they widen so much that the third gets bumped down, but if I put them each in their own `column(width = 4, ...)`, then each of them only takes up about half its column, leaving unsightly gaps between them.

Is there a way to force a box to take up its whole column?

Comment: You can try something like `box(style="width:400px;")` or `box(style="width:100%;")`. And it's always good to offer a minimum example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `box` function has a `width = 6`, you can change it to 12 to cover all the column. However, according to the shinydashboard documentation, you should set `width = NULL` for column-based layouts. See the example below.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(),
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody(
          fluidRow( 
            column(4, box(title = "box1", width = NULL)),
            column(4, box(title = "box2", width = NULL)),
            column(4, box(title = "box3", width = NULL))
          )
        )
      )

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```